# Unity child object sometimes jumps to vector3(0,0,0)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a very annoying bug, and I can't get rid of it.
The situation is, that I have a parent with the following script attached, and a trigger box2d collider. It has a child, with a rigidbody2d(kinematic, gravity=0, freeze position x, and rotation z), a sprite renderer and a polygon collider (with 4 edges).
My problem is, when the scene is loaded, sometimes my child objects (always random how much of them and which ones), jumps to transform.position 0,0,0.

I link the script, that is attached to the parent

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FallingSpikeHazard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spike;
    private Rigidbody2D spikeRigidbody;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 startPosition;

    void Awake ()
    {       
        startPosition = spike.transform.localPosition; 
    }

    void Start ()
    {
        spikeRigidbody = spike.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        
        Helper.JustReset += ResetMe;
        Invoke ("CheckPosition", Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void CheckPosition ()
    {
        if (spike.transform.localPosition != startPosition) {
            Debug.LogError ("t1" + spike.transform.localPosition);
            spike.transform.localPosition = startPosition;
            Debug.LogError ("t2" + spike.transform.localPosition);
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy ()
    {
        
        Helper.JustReset -= ResetMe;
    }

    void ResetMe ()
    {
        spikeRigidbody.gravityScale = 0;
        spikeRigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        if (startPosition != Vector3.zero) {
            spike.transform.localPosition = startPosition;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag.Equals ("Player")) {
            spikeRigidbody.isKinematic = false;
            spikeRigidbody.gravityScale = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Events are not called, in other hand, if I disable the script, it keeps happening. Nothing have reference to these GameObjects. I don't have animations, or animator attached.

What could cause my problem?

Comment: Ok guys, there is nothing wrong with the code. The problem is with the RigidBody2d Component.
Basically, if you tick the fixed x or y position, it will break your game. Literally. I put a video here to show you what is the actual bug.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HweD8A-q34Y

Comment: The solution is really simple:
if you have to use fixed angles write your own script for it.
for the x angle do this:
`public Rigidbody2d myRigidB;  
public float fixedX;  
void FixedUpdate(){  
Vector2 myVeloc = myRigidB.velocity;  
myVeloc = new Vector2(0,myVeloc.y);  
myRigidB.velocity=myVeloc;  
transform.position=new vector2(fixedX,transform.position.y);
}`

This script is not tested, but the solution is something like this :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Rigidbody2D component in the parent GameObject in order for the OnTriggerEnter function to be called.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. My problem have nothing to do with, the parents collider. My player have a rigidbody2d, and if the start is not buggy, the collision just works fine. 

I clear my problem again:
1. When I start the game some of my fallingSpike gameObjects are missing.
2. They jumps to vector3.zero
3. If I touch ANYTHING after that, my logs shows me that I was colliding with the spike gameObject, what is impossible (the new buggy position and the old position is far away from the spawn point).

Comment: 1 ) Try moving the code in Awake() to Start() because awake is called before the object is enabled. 2 ) Why are you working in local coordinates?If the spike GameObject you are passing in is a child of another object and is positioned at Vector3( 0,0,0 ) in that parent object then the spikes localPosition will return Vector3.zero.

Comment: It was in the Start() function, but there is no quite difference, because the disabled objects still have transform.position. 
The local coordinates are the result of the very sad debugging process, in the first try, it was transform.position everywhere.
My hierarchy looks like this:
-SpikeSpawner(it has the script)
   -Spike(this is the child of SpikeSpawner).
Spike's localPosition is around Vector3(0.35f, 1, 0), so there is no way to return Vector3.zero.

In other hand I would like to highlight it, that the problem is still in the program, even if the script is disabled.

Comment: I would like to help but your code already seems convoluted. I would start the object again from scratch if I were you. The spike just needs a RigidBody and a Collider and a script for collision detection. Make the spike into a prefab by dragging it into the assets folder. Then declare a public GameObject instance of a spike in your SpikeSpawner script and drag an instance of the spike prefab into the SpikeSpawner's inspector window. The SpikeSpawner should easily be able to instantiate instances of the spike prefab using Instantiate( ... )

Comment: Okay, now I'm pretty sure the problem is with the project or with my Unity. 
I removed the script, and made a debugger, what is reloading the scene after 0.1 sec. The error is still there, and there is not even one script, just these lines:  
void Start ()
 {
  Invoke ("ResetLevel", 0.1f);
 }
  
 void ResetLevel ()
 {  
  Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
 }

What the heck can it be?

Comment: Sometimes you have to turn Unity off, then on again. Sounds primitive but it often saves hours of frustration when you think there is something wrong with code that looks perfectly fine

Comment: I add a comment to the question, it is a bug in Unity's rigidbody2d component.
I was having this issue for 2 weeks now, but i figured out what it is. Tomorrow i will make a ticket in the issue tracker, because it is ridiculous